# Connecting to Outlook calendars on android

Tags: android, outlook, calendar, gdata

How do you connect to the Outlook calendar on android problematically? On the android phones I have used, outlook and google calendars are synced and show up in the same calendar app. How can I access this information. Content providers doesn't seem to work it crashes on Android 2.2.3 (see [1], in any case it was supposed to be undocumented so not really a solution). I tried using GData, but that only syncs your google calendar. It doesn't have your outlook calendar. There is another app exJello, but that only downloads your Inbox and mail information. It doesn't seem to be able to connect to outlook calendars. Looking for suggestions on a solid library or some android feature that would allow me to access the calendar information on both outlook and google. Also, assume outlook has OWA enabled.

1. http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm
2. http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html
3. http://code.google.com/p/exjello/

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.2 and higher support the Microsoft Exchange protocols (ActiveSync is the protocol family name, unless I'm wrong): this is typically the solution used to connect to Outlook calendars and requires licensing from Microsoft. For Outlook Calendars that aren't connected to an Exchange server (or for OWA) I'm not certain there is a built-in solution in Android for that, and I'm not familiar with any convenient Java libraries that will give you access that way either.

Comment: Thanks Femi. I think ActiveSync is quite separate from needing to access the exchange server via OWA. The OWA is purely https get/post based and doesn't need any licensing, just that it is enabled on the exchange side.

Comment: Quite true: ActiveSync IS different from the OWA https protocol. I know a number of connector libraries use OWA (Evolution's connector is one of them, I think) but there still isn't any Java library that I'm aware of that speaks *OWA*.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem with OWA and https is that the calendar interface seems to work only with IE (at least on exchange 2007, maybe it got fixed in exchange 2010) so even if you spoof the initial user agent, it still ends up not giving you all the information. I hoped someone did all the dirty work on this one :-), let's see if someone has suggestions.